# Seeking guidance on rtk gps topic names, message types

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will shortly release a new package that supports the swiftnav piksi rtk-gps module (http://www.swiftnav.com/piksi.html) and would like to get the message types and topic names correct. rtk-gps enables 2cm accuracy in ideal conditions, and it provides the rover position relative to a base station, which may or may not be at a surveyed location.

The driver currently publishes:

1. the gps data (3m accuracy) in message type sensor_msgs::NavSatFix on topic gps/fix
2. the rtk fix (2cm accuracy best case) in message type nav_msgs::Odometry on topic gps/rtkfix.
3. the gps time in message type sensor_msgs::TimeReference on gps/time

My question is, is this correct?

It could also publish velocity based on the rtk fix, if you think that would be useful and can suggest a message type/topic name

Since it is a gps sensor, I imagine it will frequently be a data source for robot_pose_ekf (which subscribes to nav_msgs::Odometry on topic /vo) or for robot_localization (which subscribes to message nav_msgs::Odometry on topic /odometry/gps).

Can the experts out there please guide me as to message types and topic names. I know topic names are less critical because they can be remapped, but it would be nice to make them maximally compatible.

Thanks

Paul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220684/seeking-guidance-on-rtk-gps-topic-names,-message-types/) by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 300 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-10**:
Would this be something to involve the ppl over at [ros-sig-drivers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-drivers) in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For `robot_localization`, as long as the odometry message conforms to ROS standards, then it should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on 2015-11-11**:
Thanks Tom. I believe it will work fine - the question is really if there are any maturing thoughts on topic names. If not, I'll run with what I've got.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-11-11**:
Ah, I see, sorry. For r_l, there are no fixed topic names for inputs. You specify the inputs in the config file (and not with remapping). Apologies if I'm missing your point.

**Comment by [Venkat Ganesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26837/venkat-ganesh/) on 2016-05-24**:
@PaulBouchier @TomMoore. Quick question: Am I correct in assuming the rtk-fixed GPS messages go as **nav_msgs/odometry** into a **robot_localization_node** after passing through a **navsat_transform_node**? Thanks!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-05-30**:
That is correct, yes. Feed the output of `navsat_transform_node` back into the `ekf_localization_node`.